# Google Search Appliance Broken Links For Crawled Database Content

Tags: sql-server, google-search-appliance

We are crawling SQL server for employees details. Sync is done, data is crawled and indexed. I can see result set after searching employees name from Test Center, but when I click on result set, it opens a link like `http://DOMAIN_NAME/db/HOSTNAME/DB_SOURCE_NAME/RANDOM_HASH_ID` which is 404 not found.

But when I click on Cached, it shows result properly.

Comment: what are you using to crawl the database?

Comment: I am using Google Search Appliance box version 6.10.4.G.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being 6.10 I'm guessing you're using the built in database crawler, not the offboard connector.

If that's the case then the issue is most likely the server query that you have configured or the serve URL.

On the Crawl and Index > Databases page, make sure there is a valid entry in either Serve Query or Serve URL Field.

Comment: Yes, I think serve query is wrong in my case. But I am not able to understand how to write serve query. My crawl Query and Serve Query are same "select sno, empname, empaddress from test.dbo.employee". How can I write serve query if I want to display only empname and empaddress in result set.

Comment: No worries. Perhaps you could share your fixed serve query to help anyone else that strikes similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I had configured database settings wrong in Crawl and Index->Databases->New/Edit. Crawl Query and Serve Query should not be same here. If you have table with primary key 'emp_id', your Crawl Query should be

> select emp_id, emp_name, emp_address from employee

but your Serve Query should be

> select emp_id, emp_name, emp_address from employee where emp_id = ?

and you have to set 'emp_id' in Primary Key field.

If you have more than 1 primary key(lets say emp_id and emp_name), then you can mention filter in the Serve Query like

> select emp_id, emp_name, emp_address from employee where emp_id = ?
>   and emp_name = ?